# Flume leaves .tmp file in HDFS after when changing to the new day's directory

Tags: hdfs, flume, flume-ng

I'm using Flume 1.7.0 and HDFS sink. I configured Flume to put data in the date directory in HDFS so it will automatically change the directory when the new day comes. The problem is that I set flume to roll on file size(240MB), but flume leaves .tmp files every day when the directory changes. It seems flume change to new day's directory without closing the unfinished file(smaller than 240MB).

For example. If I start 3 flume agents. Then 3 .tmp files will be left in directory 20180410 when flume agents change to new directory 20180411.

Is there a way to let flume close the .tmp files before it change to the new day's directory? Thank you all for helping me with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `hdfs.idleTimeout` to the config, so the file will be closed if no new events are added to the file, as per [documentation](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html)

> Timeout after which inactive files get closed (0 = disable automatic closing of idle files)

Note the number is seconds. A good amount to wait is at least some minutes.